# Windows 10 failed to install Wireless Display Feature

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, powershell

I'm trying to install `wireless display` feature on **Windows 10 Home**.
After several failure trough UI settings I tried trough powershell:

```
Dism.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:App.WirelessDisplay.Connect~~~~0.0.1.0
```

Uluckly even this fails with the following output:

```
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.19041.844

Image version: 10.0.19043.1237

[==========================100.0%==========================]

Error: 0x80200059

Failed to run Deployment Image Servicing and Management. Nothing was done.
 For more information, see the log file.

The Image Servicing and Management log file
 distribution is available in C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

Here's the content of the log file: [dism.log](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dpJkrYf0IsvYSOAFYPS2g79qogadAhkvspJQQBQ4wHs/edit?usp=sharing)

It seems that the problem is on some missing file from provider and/or installing of some component  ... how can I fix it?

--- Note 13/10/2021 ---

The laptop display adapter are:

- Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630
- NVIDA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti

Comment: As far as I know, this is installed by default (tested with a Surface Go with Windows 10 Home). Why are you trying to install this? Has it been uninstall for some reason?

Comment: For some reason on my MSI Laptop this was not installed and I need it to *receive* the wireless display input from a tablet

Comment: Have you tried installing it through the Windows Store?

Comment: @Ramhound yes I did and it works but the performances are pretty poor.